# Node Js: How to catch a "No such file or directory" error in readline module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a program that reads a file line by line with the readline module. First I get the file name by command line, but I want to check if the file actually exists. I have read about fs.stat() but I want to know if there is a way to catch the error directly with readline. So far I've tried this

```
try{
 var line_reader = read_line.createInterface({
  input: file_stream.createReadStream(file_name)
 });
}catch(err){
 console.log('Please insert a valid file name');
}
```

But I still get the message

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exception is thrown by createReadStream.
You need to add 'on error' case to createReadStream:

```
var fs = file_stream.createReadStream(file_name)
fs.on('error', function (err) {
                // handle error here
            });
 var line_reader = read_line.createInterface({
  input: fs
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

Miss read your question at the beginning and updated my answer.

A solution you could use [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path)

**Edit**

```
// fs.stat is async
fs.stat(file_name, function(err,stat){
   if (stat && stat.isFile() ) {
      var line_reader = read_line.createInterface({
          input: file_stream.createReadStream(file_name)
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: That would make the filesystem lookup call a blocking operation. If this is supposed to be part of an algorithm running on a webserver it could be unnecessarily inefficient. Not going to downvote for it, just an FYI.

Comment: jonathan gray here you go - none blocking now.

Comment: The Node docs say you shouldn't use .sync() to check for existence if you are reading them. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback Says you should just catch the error. But createReadStream doesn't throw (cause it's a stream). So what then?